# Receiving errors with Access OutputTo function using a variable as the file name

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to output a report as a text file, using a specific file name and path.  Below is what I am currently using and when it runs, it receive a window prompting me for the file location and name.
When I comment out "strFileName = Me.Field1" and remove the ' from the line below, it exports the file with no issues.  The value of Field1 is exactly what is used in the 2nd line.

```
Private Sub ExportFlatFile_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-1Delete"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-AdminFee"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-BF"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-CO"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-FFee"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-Fuel"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-Insp"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-Lift"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-PI"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-Pump"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-APump"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-0DeleteFileName"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "xx-FlatFile-1CreateFileName"
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = Me.Field1
'strFileName = "\\Mis-fs2\imsi2\Billing Databases\APL\WESEDI-999-198-20170119-01.txt"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptFlatFile", acFormatTXT, strFileName, False, , , acExportQualityPrint
DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)
End Sub
```

Comment: Use: `strFileName = Me!Field1.Value`

Comment: Is the above code part of the same form module with the `Field1` control?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same form.

Answer (score 0):

The '.' operator is for built-in (system) fields. The '!' operator is for named or user created fields.
You should use: `Me!Field1`

Most built in functions will bring up this kind of dialog when they can't locate the specified object.

Comment: I changed it to strFileName = Me!Field1.Value, but I received the same window ask for the file name and location.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint in the code (click at left of the line)? that will let you see the values in a variable by hovering, and you can also use the Immediate window (open with ctrl-G) to type other things and see if they work. This kind of problem is usually just some silly misspelling or something.  strFileName must end up empty, triggering the dialog.

Comment: I had to refresh Field1 prior to assigning the value to strFileName.  Thanks for the help.